# Почему индекс массива не выводится?Masiv[No error]

Tags: c

Перепробовал все что мог,всегда получается одно и тоже. В чем может быть проблема? В ответ выводится RabochiyMassiv[No error]

```
    int main() 
{
    const int n=25;
int m=0,IshodniyMassiv[n],RabochiyMassiv[m];
printf("Spisok chisel v IshodnomMassive");
for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
{
    IshodniyMassiv[i]=(rand() % 50)-5;
    printf ("\nIshodniyMassiv[%i]={%i}",i,IshodniyMassiv[i]);
    if (IshodniyMassiv[i]>=-3 && IshodniyMassiv[i]<=7)
 {
   IshodniyMassiv[i]=RabochiyMassiv[m];
  printf("\nRabochiyMassiv[%i]={%i}",RabochiyMassiv[m],i);
  m++;

  }
}
printf("\nV RabochemMassive bydet %i chisel ",m);

     getchar();
}
```

Comment: "Перепробовал все что мог," - чтобы что? "получается одно и тоже" - а именно?

Comment: Выводится [No error] вместо индекса или вообще ничего не выводится. Пытался менять значения,порядок действий.Пытался зарезервировать место для второго массива.

Comment: Что это за `%m` такой и почему вы два аргумента передаете в тот printf?

Comment: Охх,опечатался.Там [%i] должно стоять. А что,разве так делать нельзя?Поправил код в вопросе.Правда теперь в значения второго массива записываются не значения первого,а индекс первого.А в индексе второго выводится число [10419648]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He

```
IshodniyMassiv[i]=RabochiyMassiv[m];
```

a

```
RabochiyMassiv[m] = IshodniyMassiv[i];
```

---

> в выводе перепутаны местами индекс и значение

У Вас же в предыдущем `printf` правильно написано:

```
printf("\nRabochiyMassiv[%i]={%i}", m, RabochiyMassiv[m]);
```

Comment: Спасибо! Но осталась одна проблема-в выводе перепутаны местами индекс и значение. В индекс выводится значение,а в значение-индекс.Из-за чего это может быть?

Answer (score 0):

У вас рабочий массив нулевой длины:

```
int m=0,....RabochiyMassiv[m];
```